# Are requirejs dependencies recreated each time?

Tags: requirejs

I wanted to understand whether requirejs dependencies are recreated each time they are required.

For example, take a module like

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'underscore'],
   function(){
       var myObject = {
          prop1: "hello",
          prop2: "world"
       };
       return myObject;
   }
```

My question is, if I require this module in multiple modules, will all of them be using the same instance of "myObject", or independent instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always get the same instance of the object. So even if one module change the instance it will have effect in all other modules as well.